# neuroph when creating neural network nothing happens when clicking finish

Tags: java, jvm, neural-network

I can create simple small NN but when i upload a lot of images to train on (992 images) and go through all the other steps I click finish, the load bar works for a second and then nothing happens. The files don't get created and the finish screen doesn't go away.

I can also then click on Finish again and nothing happens.

I am using this as a tutorial:

http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html

I am running this on a Windows machine (Windows 7);

Is there something else i should be doing? Should i increase the Java heap size for JVM (btw how to increase the heap size in windows 7?)

Edit 1: Added more memory with: -Xms128m -Xmx3072m

still didn't help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Neuroph has its own settings when it comes to memory management:

the file that should be edited is (in my case!): `C:\Program Files\neurophstudio\etc\neurophstudio.conf`

The settings can be different for different memory needs